# Incomplete Data - Missing line segments from Oracle data

Tags: geoserver, oracle-dbms

I have setup GeoServer 2.5.2 on Windows.  Everything was going smoothly until I actually had to display my geometry data from an Oracle Database Table.  Some lines are rendered but some are not rendered.  The issue seems to be based on the type of lines (curves, etc). This issue does not happen if exporting from oracle to SqLite or Global Mapper.  In that case, all lines are kept as in the original data from Oracle.  The issue seems to be most likely with the oracle plugin (geoserver-2.5.2-oracle-plugin.zip).

Has anyone else ran into this issue and if so, how did you manage to render everything coming from Oracle in GeoServer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this GeoServer ticket and others which are referred in it http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-2935.

Support for compound curves etc. is a brand new feature in GeoServer and for the first time available in version 2.6-RC1. Great news it that you can test it immediately and perhaps send feedback to geoserver-users list before GeoServer 2.6 will be released.

Comment: 2.6-RC1 fixed the issue!  Layers shows all oracle geometry now!  Thanks.

Comment: Now if they would only update the OpenLayers Samples (Under "Layer Preview") to OpenLayers 3 before GeoServer 2.6 is released would be awesome!

Comment: Looks promising https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-6643